# Best way of getting the list of html values and populating them in a backbone-requirejs application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Here is the scenario, the page is made of backbone views (multiple views, around 20) and about 30 templates. All structured using requirejs architecture. But some of the values in the template such as heading tiles, sub heading titles and drop down values come from a single json object returned by an ajax request during page load. How do I pass these values around multiple templates?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly then you can do in the following way:

**[Link to jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nicolai8/6Wjc4/)**

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/template" id="modelTemplate">
    <h1 data - id = "<%=Id%>" > <%= Name %> </h1>
        <ul>
            <%_.each(Titles,function(title){%>  
                <%=_.template($("#titleTemplate").html())(title)%>     
            <%});%>      
       </ul>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="titleTemplate">
    <li> <%= Name %>
        <ul>
            <%_.each(SubTitles,function(subTitle){%>  
                <%=_.template($("#subTitleTemplate").html())(subTitle)%>     
            <%});%>       
        </ul>
   </li>
</script>
<script type="text/template" id="subTitleTemplate">
    <li> <%= Name %> </li>
</script>
```

And **JavaScript** (instanceOfModel is some model that you populates with ajax request):

```
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({});

var instanceOfModel = new model({
    Id: 1,
    Name: "Some Name",
    Titles: [{
        Name: "First Title",
        SubTitles: [{
            Name: "SubTitle Name 1"
        }, {
            Name: "SubTitle Name 2"
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "SecondTitle",
        SubTitles: [{
            Name: "SubTitle Name 3"
        }, {
            Name: "SubTitle Name 4"
        }]
    }, {
        Name: "Last Title",
        SubTitles: [{
            Name: "SubTitle Name 5"
        }, {
            Name: "SubTitle Name 6"
        }]
    }]
});

var modelTemplate = _.template($("#modelTemplate").html());

$("#container").append(modelTemplate(instanceOfModel.toJSON()));
```